# Angular call on JSON arrays

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

> I want to output the title of test1 from the first array and the title
>   of test2 from the second array, any help would be great. Thanks

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 21,
            "title": "test1",
             "identifier": null,
            "colour_bg": "#bd2c2c",
            "colour_btn": "#a11212",
            "colour_content_bg": "#ffffff",
            "logo_dashboard": "collection/21/SVwnz6tjluX81dIRNXjZo7issYUWyOVyD3LJFykm.png",
            "logo_page": "collection/21/txgkqlkPA45mHSYtqZ5rFa4wLfHNUfXESE0xyhwp.png"
        }
    ],
     "links": [
        {
            "id": 21,
            "title": "test2",
             "identifier": null,
            "colour_bg": "#bd2c2c",
            "colour_btn": "#a11212",
            "colour_content_bg": "#ffffff",
            "logo_dashboard": "collection/21/SVwnz6tjluX81dIRNXjZo7issYUWyOVyD3LJFykm.png",
            "logo_page": "collection/21/txgkqlkPA45mHSYtqZ5rFa4wLfHNUfXESE0xyhwp.png"
        }
    ]
}

My HTML below 
 <div *ngFor="let result of data">
        <h1>{{result.title}}</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this :

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvhwcg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

in ts file :

```
loadUser() {
    this.http.get('assets/json/collection.json')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
            console.log('this.data', this.data);
        })
}
```

template

```
<div *ngFor="let result1 of data.results">
        <div *ngFor="let result2 of data.links">
          <h1>{{result1.title}}</h1>
          <h1>{{result2.title}}</h1>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: loadUser(){

      this.http.get('assets/json/collection.json')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data.results;
        
        console.log(data.results);
      });
    }

Comment: That is my function I think i am only calling the result array there?

Comment: Yes. you are assigned only results array change it `.subscribe(data => { this.data = data; }` instead of `.subscribe(data => { this.data = data.results; }`

Comment: I have done that now nothing is showing in the html page?

Comment: i have updated my answer refer this and try like this in your typescript and check the log if value is correct

Comment: Just a little of topic, is it possible to change the background colour of an ionic page from the JSON value?

Comment: Its okay ive sorted it   <div *ngFor="let result2 of data.links">
        <button [navPush]="schedulePage" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': result2.colour_btn}" ion-button large><p>{{result2.title}}</p></button></div> if that helps anyone

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let result of data; let idx = index">
        <h1>{{result.title}}</h1>
        <h1>{{links[idx].title}}</h1>
    </div>
```